# Not Transcribing short answers

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, transcription

I am using Twilio to call my cell phone.  I need to respond with a short Yes or No answer.  This is working correctly and recording.  However, the next step is to transcribe this and then determine what to do based upon the transcription.  If I leave a longer message, while it is not very accurate it does transcribe my recording.  But it does not transcribe a short Yes or No answer.   I know there is a max time of 120 seconds, is there a minimum time too?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use transcription to achieve what you need. Twilio's transcription is not real time, and you will not be able to respond with a Twiml to alter the call path.

To achieve this result, I had to use tropo.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio will not transcribe anything under 3 seconds.
See https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133007-Transcriptions-are-blank-for-short-recordings